# Hardware info using mac osx and c

Tags: c, macos, hardware

I know there is a system_profiler command that returns information on mac and I also saw someone mention that the source code of that command hasn't been made public.

How does one find that information considering that the code has to be written in C only? I would like to retrive as much as I can using the code and not call a command and parse its output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sysctl() function may give you the info you want.

In your terminal type

```
man -s3 sysctl
```

Comment: I am looking at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-541/sysctl.tproj/sysctl.c?txt link and I saw that there is a call to sysctl in that program. Of course this is just a sample but if I am read it properly isn't it calling that command to get the output?

I am new to programming on OSX and so do excuse me if I am asking some stupid questions here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sysctl() can be used to read and if your process has permission write. There is a commanline version 'man -s8 sysctl' which you can play around with to see if it gives you the info you want.

Comment: I see what you were saying. I was able to look up more about sysctl and was able to use it. Thanks.